# What version of Javascript is universally supported?

Tags: google-cast

I have developed a Google Cast receiver app. It was working quite well on my Chromecast (1st gen). But when I tried it on a Google Cast speaker (audio only, the LG H4), I got Javascript errors. The `let` keyword apparently is not supported.

So the question becomes: Which version of javascript is universally supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably `ES5` as the standard was set in 2009. You can use babel, a nodejs library, with `gulp` or `webpack` or whatever build system (even make) to transpile your `ECMA-2015/ES6` code into `ES5`.

- [Info on ES2015 features](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/).
- [Setup babel - Pick a build system](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/).